retrofit create() throws java NoClassDefFoundError
I am writing a unit test in kotlin, to test a retrofit service. It ran as expected when I had dependent classes defined in the Test file, outside of the test class. That was for experimenting, and I next moved those classes to their own files in Production.
The Retrofit.create(BudgetApiService) now throws a class not defined error when I run the test.
The specific line in the code is
val retrofitService : BudgetApiService = retrofit.create(BudgetApiService::class.java)
The error is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/marsphotos/network/BudgetApiService
I want to use the retrofit service to get data, to be verified.

I tried debugging.
One of related answers points suggests the error is due to my classpath settings. Perhaps this question should be about how to set up test classes in Android Studio. I am learning this tool.
I have removed all non relevant code. The simplified version is listed below.

package com.example.marsphotos.network
import org.junit.Test
import retrofit2.Retrofit

class NetworkBudgetRepositoryTest{
    @Test
    fun networkBudgetRepository_requestGET_verifyRequestURL() {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://dummy")
            .build()

        val retrofitService : BudgetApiService =

This is where the error is thrown
            retrofit.create(BudgetApiService::class.java) 

        val categories = retrofitService.getCategories()


    }

}


And this is the "not found" class:
package com.example.marsphotos.network
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface BudgetApiService {
    @GET("budget")
    fun getCategories() : List<BudgetCategory>
}

Answer pointing to Classpath setup
